# I am getting Timeout expired error

Tags: c#

System.Data; Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
this error will come only when i run service

i am using below code

```
try
{
    LogGenerator.WriteErrorLog("Conn opened before");
    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
    con.Open();
    LogGenerator.WriteErrorLog("Conn opened");
    // Set up a command with the given query and associate
    // this with the current connection.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Backup database " + DBName + " to disk='" + filePathExist + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    LogGenerator.WriteErrorLog("query executed");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    LogGenerator.WriteErrorLog("Error in Conn");
    LogGenerator.WriteErrorLog(ex);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
    SqlConnection.ClearPool(con);
}
```

Comment: By default cmd will have 30 seconds for CommandTimeout . If your backup run longer, it causes Timeout error. So I think you should increase CommandTimeout  before cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your trying take DB backup sometime it will take more than default connection time, so try to set timeout to your command.

```
try
{    
    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
      con.Open();    
// Set up a command with the given query and associate
// this with the current connection.
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Backup database " + DBName + " to disk='" + 
   filePathExist + "'", con);
   cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
}    
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //handle exception here
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
    SqlConnection.ClearPool(con);
}
```

for more information on timeout please refer here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-login-timeout-server-configuration-option